# Can't install DoctrineMigrationsBundle with Symfony3 using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony, doctrine-migrations

I'm fairly new to Symfony and figured I'd follow their instructions (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) to install and config a new project using Symfony.

I chose the "Creating Symfony Applications without the Installer" option and created a new project using composer:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

I followed the rest of the instructions to the letter and got my app up and running. So far so good. Now I wanted to install database migrations using the DoctrineMigrationsBundle as they suggest (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html). And that's where things got hairy.

Their page says "2.1 version" at the top with no alternative version to select. Which I guess means the instructions are meant for Symfony2.1. I went ahead and ran the listed command anyway. I mean how much can have changed about the basic installation process?

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.0"
```

That leads to a whole bunch of errors from composer telling me it can't resolve the requirements (see below) and where I got hung up. I tried to install a couple other versions of the bundle and other components and googled the hell out of the problem, but couldn't find anything.

```
./composer.json has been updated
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 1.0.1 requires doctrine/migrations ~1.0@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 1.1.1 requires doctrine/migrations ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v1.1.0 requires doctrine/migrations ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- doctrine/migrations v1.0.0 requires symfony/console ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
- doctrine/migrations v1.1.0 requires symfony/console ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 1.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/console v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
- Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.1, v1.1.0].
```

Sorry for the bad output, but for the love of god I can't figure out how to format it properly :/

Anway, if anyway could shove me in the right direction how to install DoctrineMigrationsBundle with Symfony3, that'd be real great.

Maybe it's not compatible yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migration bundle require [Doctrine/Migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations).

Doctrine migrations require symfont 2.* components (yml reader for example), see latest [composer.json](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/v1.1.0/composer.json)

You require symfony 3.* witch require yml redeader version 3.*

Conflict can't be resolved.

If you read the output you will see the same.

Comment: Meaning migrations don't work with Symfony3 (yet). So no migrations for me...damn. Guess I'm going back to SF2 then.

Comment: There is "fix" for v3 in master branch. Maybe they will release new version soon

Answer (score 3):

Dev version supports Symfony 3.

Add to `composer.json`

to root:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

to `require`:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

and run `composer update`

Comment: But I don't want to use dev branches on production, so that's not an option until it's in master and considered stable. But thanks anyway!